# Find compiler for C167 Siemens

Tags: c, gcc, microcontroller

Does the **gcc 166 compiler** for the **Siemens C167** micro controller exist in open source ?, or can I find it?

Comment: If a version of gcc targeted it, then yes, it was free software since gcc uses the GPL.

Comment: Some quick searching suggests that gcc never targeted that platform, though. Looks like there were only closed-source commercial compilers for it.

Comment: I think that the "166" dont mean the version of GCC but gcc 166 means another sorts of compiler based on GCC for specific hardware

Comment: @Shawn GCC 166 isn't a version of the GCC compiler but it used by the C167 controller(external hardware) to be controlled by a computer, here a similar question [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.arch.embedded/fsclqYwlYoY]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the site [link](http://www.rigelcorp.com) I found that **GCC 166** it is a compiler available for sale by **Rigel corp**